# Mould growing on top of plant soil?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

There seems to be some white mould growing on top of my vining philodendron soil.

Is this is problem and if so how can I resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the soil in the pot? was it new potting soil, or something else because there seems to be a lot of small debris in the soil?

Comment: @bamboo- thanks for your comment. I don't actually know about the soil, I bought it like this. Would the soil cause mould issues? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white stuff is hyphae or fungal strands; the soil in the pot seems to have some debris (uncomposted material) and this is probably why the fungal strands are there. The other factor needed to produce this type of fungus is moisture, but the soil in the pot does not look wet. It will not affect the health of your plant, but if you don't like constantly seeing the fungal growth, you could repot the plant, using new, sterilised potting soil. If you do this, shake or tease off what soil you can, especially from the top, but without damaging root material and then repot using the new soil. If you want to reuse the same pot because the roots don't really require a larger one, give it a good wash in soapy water and rinse well first.